# How I can show that $\lim_{(x, y)\to (3, 4)} xy = 12$?

Tags: limits

How I can show that $$\lim_{(x, y)\to (3, 4)} xy = 12$$ by definition? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\forall$ $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < ||(x, y) - (3, 4)|| < \delta$ then $|xy - 12| < \epsilon$. But I honestly do not know how to start.

Comment: I know that $||(x, y) - (3, 4)|| = \sqrt{(x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2}$ and $|x - 3| < \delta$, $|y - 4| < \delta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If you write
$$
xy-12=(x-3+3)(y-4+4)-12=(x-3)(y-4)+4(x-3)+3(y-4)
$$
it will fit pretty good to the usual $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definition of limit. Ask if you need further steps, but please try hard yourself first.