# Working with limits of functions of the type $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to jump doing $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs of the limit of functions of one variable (i.e. $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$), to functions of two variables (i.e. $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$) and I am struggling since some of the methods I learned for one variable do not immediately carry for two variables. Unfortunately, I find that my books are too eager to jump to nice theorems to calculate limits (limit of a sum is equal to the sum of the limits, etc.) but I insist on being able to find limits to the most elementary functions like $x+y,xy, x^2 + y^2, \frac{x}{y}, \frac{1}{x+y}$ using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition (without more advanced notions like the topology of $\mathbb{R^n}$) of the limit until I gain some intuition to move on and prove more general theorems using this technique. In this post, I will show you one case I think I was able to work out correctly, and another where I am struggling.

1) Perharps the simplest case I could think was to show that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}(x+y) = a+b$$.

In this case, the definition says that $f(x,y)=(x+y) \to (a+b)$ when $(x,y) \to (a,b)$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that for all $(x,y)$ in the domain of $f$, whenever $0<\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$, we have $|f(x,y) - (a+b)|<\epsilon$. For this, all I had to do was to realize that $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$ implies that $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-b|<\delta$, therefore $|x + y - a -b| \le |x-a| + |y-b| < 2\delta$, therefore I should choose $\delta = \epsilon/2$. Is this line or reasoning correct?

2) Now, consider

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}xy = ab
$$

working backwards, I want

$$
\begin{align}
|xy - ab| &< \epsilon\\
|(x-a+a)(y-b+b) -ab| &<\epsilon \\
|(x-a)(y-b) +b(x-a) +a(y-b)| &< \epsilon \qquad (*) \\
&\vdots\\
\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}&<\delta
\end{align}
$$

(*) I got this idea from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431753/how-i-can-show-that-lim-x-y-to-3-4-xy-12). But that's it I am afraid. I don't know how to take it from there. I would appreciate any hint or guidance. Sorry if this post is too long. I wanted to provide context and background and would be happy to edit or split questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equivalent?
If so: Just use a norm that's more suitable to your problem, like the maximum norm for example ...
That will save you lots of difficult calculations!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have heard about that, but not worked with it yet and do not know how to use it. I know that technically we have  $\forall\epsilon >0, \exists\delta>0$ such that whenever $||\mathbf{x - x_0}||< \delta$ we have $||f(\mathbf{x}) - L||<\epsilon$ where the double bars indicate the norm and $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)$ and $\mathbf{x_0} = (a,b)$, and $L = a+b$ if we applied it to this problem. I will keep it in mind and come back if I get stuck trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

$ |x-a| \le \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$, and

$|y-b| \le \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose

$\delta < \min(1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+|a|+|b|})$.

Then

$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} \lt \delta$ implies

$|xy-ab| \le$

$ |x-a||y-b| +$

$|b||x-a| +|a||y-b| \lt$

$(\delta)^2+(|b|+|a|)\delta \lt $

$(1+|a|+|b|)\delta \lt \epsilon.$

Note: $(\delta)^2 \lt \delta$ for

$ \delta =\min (1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{1+|a|+|b|})$.

Comment: Thank you! that was very clear. However. Can I ask you how did you figure you will need $\delta = \min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{1+|a|+|b|}\right)$? I learned that to do that, I should work backwards from the conclusion, and doing so, I can follow until you have $|x-a||y-b| +|a||y-b| +|b||x-a| < \delta^2 +(1+|a|+|b|)\delta$. At this point, I would say that I want this expression in terms of $\delta$ to be equal to $\epsilon$, but I am not sure how to deduce that particular $\delta$. For instance, how (and why) you concluded you will need $\delta=1$?

Comment: Fernando. You were almost there.Use line 1)2) in the above answer you get |x-a|< delta and |y-b|<delta.In your expression write tentatively: |x-a||y-b|<(delta)^2 ,the other terms |b||x-a| <|b|delta and |a||y-b|<|a|delta. Choosing delta <1 will make (delta)^2<delta.So factor the deltas and then you see by choosing delta =epsilon/(1+|a|+|b|) you are done.Do not forget we use \delta <1 so we need the minimum.ok?

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Fernando.Welcome.Do a few similar exercises and you become a master.:))